# How to include tsv/csv header in bash script output

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk, sed

I have thousands of `.tsv` files where I am extracting the rows where column 2 is equal column 6.

I can use the below bash script, but I could not append column names (header) in the output.

What is the way to include header?

```
for x in *.tsv; do
   awk '$2==$6' <"$x" >"$x.tmp"
   mv "$x.tmp" "$x"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print based on two conditions, say so:

```
awk 'FNR==1 || $2==$6' file
```

This will print those lines that either of these:

- match the `$2==$6` condition.
- are the first line.

Also, note you don't need to loop with bash, `awk` can do it:

```
awk '(FNR==1 || $2==$6) {print > FILENAME".bk"}' *.tsv
```

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I needed.Thanks

Comment: Also, How do you invert this equal condition? I mean, to extract the rows that are not equal.

Comment: @MAPK you can say `$2 != $6`.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to awk/bash. Sounds similar to perl/python or R with most regex and conditions.

Comment: @MAPK it is sooooo nice. Interesting reading: [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/)